# JSON.net Linq and NullValueHandling

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

Developing a new MVC4 app, I have followed this [example](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDeclaratively.htm) on the JSON.net website to fill my viewmodel with a new JSON JObject:

```
FinalViewModel finalVM= new FinalViewModel();
IList<ResultModel> results = GetResultList();

FinalVM.QueryResults = results;

JObject myJSON = new JObject(
    new JProperty("grid",
    new JArray(
    from g in results
    group g by g.ResultYear into y
    orderby y.Key
    select new JObject {
    new JProperty("Year", y.Key),
    new JProperty("min_1",  y.Min(g=> g.Result_val1)),
    new JProperty("min_2",  y.Min(g=> g.Result_val2)),
    new JProperty("items",
        new JArray(
            from g in results
            where g.ResultYear==y.Key
            orderby g.id
            select new JObject(                                               
                    new JProperty("l", g.Result_val1),
                    new JProperty("j",g.Result_val2),                                                  
                    new JProperty("id", g.id)
                )
            )

        )}
)));



FinalVM.DataJson = myJSON;

return PartialView("_JSONView", FinalVM);
```

Everything works fine and i get this type of json sent to my view:

```
{
     "grid": [
        {
            "Year": 1998,           
            "min_val1": "12",
            "min_val2": null,
            "items": [
                {
                    "l": 12,
                    "j": null,
                    "id": 60
                },
                {
                    "l": 25,
                    "j": null,                    
                    "id": 61
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
```

I would like to get rid of the null values when they exist. I read a lot about the `NullValueHandling` option but do not see how to use it into my Json.Net linq code.

Comment: My approach would be to first get the actual object from a service layer and then just serialize that object rather than to mess up with the `JProperty`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating `JObjects` as part of your LINQ transformation, use anonymous objects.  (This will also make your code a heck of a lot more readable!)  Afterward, you can load the result object into a `JObject` using a `JsonSerializer` instance that has `NullValueHandling` set to `Ignore`.  This will get rid of the nulls.  Here's a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<ResultModel> results = new List<ResultModel>
        {
            new ResultModel
            {
                id = 60,
                ResultYear = 1998,
                Result_val1 = 12,
                Result_val2 = null
            },
            new ResultModel
            {
                id = 61,
                ResultYear = 1998,
                Result_val1 = 25,
                Result_val2 = null
            }
        };

        var groupedResult = new
        {
            grid = from g in results
                   group g by g.ResultYear into y
                   orderby y.Key
                   select new
                   {
                       Year = y.Key,
                       min_1 = y.Min(g => g.Result_val1),
                       min_2 = y.Min(g => g.Result_val2),
                       items = from g in results
                               where g.ResultYear == y.Key
                               orderby g.id
                               select new
                               {
                                   l = g.Result_val1,
                                   j = g.Result_val2,
                                   id = g.id
                               }
                   }
        };

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        JObject myJSON = JObject.FromObject(groupedResult, serializer);

        Console.WriteLine(myJSON.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
    }

    class ResultModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int ResultYear { get; set; }
        public int? Result_val1 { get; set; }
        public int? Result_val2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "grid": [
    {
      "Year": 1998,
      "min_1": 12,
      "items": [
        {
          "l": 12,
          "id": 60
        },
        {
          "l": 25,
          "id": 61
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

One other note: if you are not planning to manipulate the JSON, you can actually skip the `JObject` altogether and serialize your grouped result directly to string instead:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

string myJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupedResult, settings);
```